# My remote server doesn't let my host use header file

Tags: c, ubuntu, remote-debugging, clion

I am using CLion to debug my code remotely. My machine is windows and I am using a virtual machine that is Ubuntu Linux. I am trying to use #include "ncurses.h" file for my code but it doesn't me and this is the error:

```
Cannot open file 'C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2020.3\.remote\321-327VM_22\cff0ded9-509b-4449-922f-f335b09c8624\usr\include\ncurses.h': permission denied
```

how to solve this problem? I already changed the file permissions to read write and execute by everyone.

Comment: Did you also check access rights for all the folders in the path?

Comment: yes, no problem there

Comment: Do you have rsync installed on remote host?

Answer (score 0):

Permission error is about user priveleges and file permissions. First you can see the file permissions by:

```
ls -l
```

And to change it you can switch to root user by:

```
sudo su
```

And change file permissions by

```
chmod +x
```

or

```
chmod 777
```

chmod command means "change mod", it has 3 digit 3 area for different users: (chmod --- --- --- 9 digit)

- The three leftmost characters, rwx, define permissions for the User class
- The middle three characters, rwx, define permissions for the Group class (i.e. the group owning the file)
- the last three characters, ---, define permissions for the Others class. In this example, users who are not the owner of the file and who are not members of the Group (and, thus, are in the Others class) have no permission to access the file.

First digit is read digit for example 1--1--1-- (chmod 444) is readable by all.
Second digit is write digit, -1--1--1- chmod(222)is writable by all.
The last is execute digit, --1--1--1 chmod(111) this is executable by all.

Giving 777 meaning 111111111, all permissions for all user.

Comment: You missed the last line: "I already changed the file permissions to read write and execute by everyone."

Comment: Yes you are right, i ll think about the problem then.